# GlassFish 4.1 - simultaneous access to web admin console of two domains of the same GF

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-4

I use GlassFish 4.1 - final release (downloaded from java.net). I have two domains - domain1 and domain2

The problem is that I can't work simultaneously with web admin console of two domains of the same GF server. I open admin of domain1 - everything is ok, at the same browser (firefox) but different tab I open admin console of domain2 - at this time server closes my access for the admin of domain1. What is the reason? How can it be fixed?

Comment: What's the URL of domain1 and domain2 console?

Comment: @gerrytan domain1- http://192.168.1.10:portN, domain2 - http://192.168.1.10:portM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is simply because you're accessing the two domains via URLs with the same host.

```
192.168.1.10:X
192.168.1.10:Y
```

Recall that the host portion is `192.168.1.10` and as with many other web-app, glassfish admin console use session cookies, which is *unique per host*. So what happen when you login to the second domain is, the session info from the first domain is lost / overwritten.

Easiest solution for this is use a different browser for each domain (eg: firefox for domain 1 and IE for domain 2) or open another window in incognito mode (if using google chrome)